# Changing background-color of td on checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I do this? I have a `checkbox` that when you click/check the full `td` column will be having a background color. Then if it is unchecked, it will remove its background-color. Also if it is checked already and the user checked another `checkbox`, the one checked will have the background-color and the previous one will have no background color.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s79hv0uu/)

Comment: just clarifying your question ... you want to change the background-color of the full column when the top checkbox is checked, correct?

Comment: Well I added a Snippet so that people don't downvote your post. Good Luck!

Comment: yes. that's what i need to do. @PlantTheIdea

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Ya, really really boring! Anyway thx for trying ;)

Comment: @Jennifer You have to post relevant code in question! Anyway, your HTML markup is invalid, IDs must be unique on document context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just add a col tags to your HTML table. You can then set the background-color of the col and will make all the TDs in the column that color:

```js
function ChangeColColor(chkCol,col) {
   var varCol = document.getElementById(col);
   var varColor = "White";
   if (chkCol.checked == true) {
       varColor = "Red";
   }
   varCol.style.backgroundColor = varColor;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col id="colA">
      <col id="colB">
        <col id="colC">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>Column A <input id="chkColA" type="checkbox" onclick="ChangeColColor(this,'colA')"/></td>
    <td>Column B <input id="chkColB" type="checkbox" onclick="ChangeColColor(this,'colB')"/></td>
    <td>Column C <input id="chkColC" type="checkbox" onclick="ChangeColColor(this,'colC')"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data A:1</td>
    <td>Data B:1</td>
    <td>Data C:1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data A:2</td>
    <td>Data B:2</td>
    <td>Data C:2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data A:3</td>
    <td>Data B:3</td>
    <td>Data C:3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```js
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('green')
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false).parent().removeClass('green');
});
```

```css
.green  {
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
 
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```